# how to read this file using tesseract(python)?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

how to read this png file using tesseract?

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: Seems to be a captcha....this is base64...you need to decode

Answer (score 0):

Decoding Captcha isn't easy job, but maybe this example would be helpful.
In order to recognize text from Captcha you need more magic with cv2.

```
bfile='blablabla' #your base64 image
ffile=bfile.decode('base64')
pl=open('capcha.png','wb')
pl.write(ffile)
pl.close()
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('capcha.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print (text)
```